# Number of rolls until the same number appears 2 consecutive times

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I don't think the formula given here: [Expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69373/expected-number-of-rolls-until-a-number-appears-k-times) is correct.
For example what's the expected number of rolls before two consecutive 6's -- 66? It should be 42, not 7, as their formula suggests. The number 42 can be easily calculated using Wald's identity and the smoothing property (6 + 1 = 7 and, then, 7 * 6 = 42). Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: In that question they care about *any* number appearing $k$ times, whereas you care about a *specific* number appearing $k$ times. Naturally your expected number is $6$ times higher.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for the question you linked specifies the expected number of rolls to get *any number $k$ times*, which is $7$ for $k=2$, while the problem you refer to is the expected number of rolls to get a *particular number $k$ times*, here $6$, which is $42$ for $k=2$. This intuitively seems correct as well because $42=6\times7$, and you have $6$ possible numbers on a die.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter that both are 6's, right? For example, the answer (42) should be the same if I ask "what's the expected time before 54", or "before 12". The answer to both is still 42? In general "expected number of throws before 55555" should be the same as "expected number of throws before 12321", right? (meaning the exact numbers don't matter).

Comment: @ajfbiw.s No, it does matter. Look at it this way. Suppose you have a 6. Then, if the next number is a 6, you have a success, and if not a failure. In case of a failure, you start afresh, so the expected number of throws after that is the same as the overall expected number of throws. However, in the case of a 54, if the first throw is a 5, and the second is a 4, you have a success, but if the second throw is a 5, it is a failure and yet you _do not start afresh_. So, intuitively, you can see that they are different.