# How to derive the expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ consecutive times

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

In [Expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ consecutive times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69373/expected-number-of-rolls-until-a-number-appears-k-times), the formula was given to be $E[N] = \frac{6^k - 1}{5}$. You can prove this formula using induction like in the accepted answer.

I am wondering how do you actually derive this expression from scratch?

Comment: The question you linked to is actually about the expected number of rolls until a number appears $k$ **consecutive** times, although the important modifier "consecutive" was misleadingly left out of the title. The answer $\frac{6^k-1}5$ is for $k$ **consecutive** appearances. If that's the problem you're interested in, you should clarify your question by adding the word "consecutive" in the right places. On the other hand, if you're interested in the waiting time until some number has appeared $k$ times (not necessarily consecutively), that's another question.

Comment: I hope your question was for consecutive appearances. That's what I worked out, seeing the link. Pl clarify immediately what you intended, and make necessary amendments.

Comment: @bof Ahhhh I missed that part. I was unfortunately interested in the non-consecutive case. I'll change this question to the consecutive case anyways since someone already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $e$ the expected value of getting, say, $6$ on a die roll, then $e =\frac{1}{p} = 6\;$ by the geometric distribution.

The final result is just the sum of the G.P. representing  repeating the result of the first toss $(k-1)$ more times in succession

$1 + e + e^2 + ....e^{k-1} = \frac {e^k-1}{e-1} =\frac{6^k-1}{6-1}$

---

*Added: Formula derivation*

I am changing the symbol $e$ used above to $e_1$, to specify that it means the expected value for getting *one* six, $e_1 = 6$ from the geometric distribution

From there, we have $\frac16$ chance of getting double $6$, else back to scratch with a wasted throw, so $\;e_2 = e_1 +\frac16\cdot1 + \frac56(e_2 +1) \to\; e_2 = 6(e_1+1)$

We compute for $(k-1)$ more successive sixes using recursion

$\displaylines {e_2 = 6(e_1+1)=6+6^2\\e_3= 6(e_2+1) = 6 + 6^2+6^3\\e_4 = 6(e_3+1) = 6 + 6^2 +6^3+6^4\\ ... ...\\e_k = 1+ e_{k-1} = 1+6+6^2+6^3 +...6^{k-1} = \frac{6^k-1}{6-1}}$

Comment: Wait is $e_k$ the expected number of tosses to get a fixed number k times in a row, or the expected number of tosses it takes to any number $k$ times in a row?

Comment: In eithe rscenario, I think there's an issue with this formula because for $k=1$, your solution is undefined.

Comment: It is not a **particular** number, it is **any** number, ("**a** number" and $k=1$ is precluded because of the phrasing *k* **consecutive** times.