# Actual odds of making it to the final room

Tags: probability

This question comes from my wanting to understand the true odds of this game.

I'm making a game on a Minecraft server that is based on Iskall85's RUN game from the Hermitcraft series.  Here's how the game works...

Players have a 50/50 chance of the front door opening after they pay so they can play a run through of the game.
In the 1st room, they will trigger a 50/50 chance that they will be killed and have to start over, or they will make it to the next room.

The 2nd room has 2 50/50 triggers to either kill them or let them move on...and both must be passed in order to move on.

The next 2 rooms will require some skill needed to complete and I'll have to try to figure out how to work out the odds on those later.

Since each Failure ends the run, I feel like the odds should be along this line:

| Front Door | 1st room | 2nd Room 1st trigger | 2nd room 2nd trigger |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F |  |  |  |
| S | F |  |  |
| S | S | F |  |
| S | S | S | F |
| S | S | S | S |

Would this mean that there is a 1 in 5 chance of making it through the 2nd room completely?  There would be no further outcomes if they fail at any point, so those extra chances shouldn't count...right?

Comment: No, your probabilities are all 0.5=1/2 (if I understand you correctly). Assuming independence, you would multiply them to get the final probability of  making it past the second room as 1/16. The rows  in your table are "not equally likely".

Comment: No, the events are not equally likely, so you can't calculate it like that. If we assume the various 50/50 chances are independent (i.e. the outcome of one does not affect the outcome of another), you can multiply the chances (expressed as numbers, and each 50/50 corresponds to a $0,5$, so the chance of getting through the first two rooms (where there are 4 "triggers") are $0.5^4 = 0.125$.

Comment: Does the first door not accepting payment count as failure? If so, you have your answer by JMP.

Comment: Frame challenge: this game doesn't sound fun at all for the players.

Comment: @Rdstr: You have written that "they will be killed and **have to start over**, or..." If you have to start over each time you fail, the probability  of getting through the first two rooms will be much lower. Please clarify this point. The answers of $Pr = 1/16$ are assuming that you succeed at each step.

Comment: The original was very addicting for some members of that server.  I recreated the game on a server a few years ago and it was very successful.  However, I plan on changing the game some this time around and want to have a better idea of what to charge and what to reward.

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, if they fail after the front door, they will have to start over completely.

Comment: Based on this comment, I have put up an answer according to the rules of the game.

Comment: @true blue anil, and? the OP asked the probability of successfully crossing all the levels and that is 1/16, also when he says start over I'm considering the player to start from the absolute beginning.

Comment: @Aadi Sinha: You are missing the point that the person can fail at any door, and has to restart. It is a back and forth process, have a look at this problem which is on die throws rather than coins, the principle is the same.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105305/how-to-derive-the-expected-number-of-rolls-until-a-number-appears-k-consecutiv/4105476#4105476

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your latest remark, we should count the number of times a person will have to pay for playing the game before success, that is why I said that the probability will be much lower with returning to start after each failure. We shall need to proceed step by step, starting with, s_0, and moving step by step to ultimately get to s_4

The equations to be solved for this game will be  as below:
The first equation can be understood as saying that with $1$ payment, there is a probability of $1/2$ of moving to $s_1$ (stage $1$) or returning to start, needing to pay again. And so on until you eventually jump from $s_3$ to success

$\displaylines {s_0 =1+ (1/2)*s_1 + (1/2)*s_0\\ s_1=1+ (1/2)*s_2 + (1/2)*s_0\\ s_2=1+(1/2)*s_3 + (1/2)*s_0\\s_3= 1 +(1/2)*s_0} $

This yields $s_0=30$, which means that the player will have to pay $30$ times on an average before "success" which implies a probability of $\Large\frac1{30}$ rather than $\Large\frac 1{16}$

---

## Simplified answer

Instead of many equations, we can get one general equation

Denote the expected number of tosses to get a run of $n$ successive heads as $E(n)$

Then from $E(n-1)$, with one toss, we are either done,  or with probability $1/2$, we have to start all over again, so

$E(n)=  E(n-1)\;+1 + (1/2)*E(n)$

This simplifies to $E(n) = 2[E(n-1)\;+1],$ so

$E(1)=2,$
$E(2) = 2*3 = 6$,
$E(3) = 2*7 = 14$,
$E(4)= 2*15 = 30$

and $Pr = \Large\frac 1{30}$

*Note that you can now easily extend the computations for larger runs, as you have hinted will be needed afterwards*

Comment: sorry but en=(en−1+1)+(1/2)∗en alone doesn't make much sense, and may i ask why there has to be a finite en such that i get n consecutive heads, I can throw a coin infinitely many times and not get n consecutive heads.

Comment: @AadiSinha: 1) Yes, the coin task experiment can theoretically extend to infinity, we are computing the **expected value** . Have you been taught the concept of expected value ? The formula I have used doesn't make sense to you, do the results obtained from it make sense or not ? 2) Re the formula: do the results obtained make sense ? Maybe you misinterpreted the formula. I will shortly edit it so that there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You have a $\frac{1}{16}$ chance of success - you have to survive $4$ throws of the FS coin.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in view of the clarification given by OP in comments under the question

Answer (score 0):

The person has simply a $\frac{1}{16}$ chance of clearing the Front door, first room and second room. Hence the overall probability is $P(S) = P(S_0)P(S_1)P(S_2)$  where $\\P(S_2) = 1/4 ,\ P(S_0) = 1/2 ,\ P(S_1) = 1/2 $.

Even though according to the sample space you've made, it seems that there exist only 5 possibilities so the probability of success must be 1/5, however the probability of all those cases are not same for example, players chance of failure at the front door is 50% and not 20%

Comment: This answer is incorrect in view of the clarification given by OP in comments under the question